# Content script cannot find created elements?

Tags: javascript, firefox, add-on, content-script

I'm trying to make the toolbar button (the browser toolbar) in my extension toggle a div on and off.  However, I'm finding that the content script can't find any objects I create.

Here's the code where upon first click, the div is created.  But upon 2nd click, it just creates another, when it should have found the last one and removed it:

main.js:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "style-tab",
  label: "Style Tab",
  icon: "./icon-16.png",
  onClick: function() {

    worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("my-script.js")
    });
    worker.port.emit("myaction", "whatever");
  }
});
```

my-script.js:

```
var div = 0;
self.port.on("myaction", function(color) {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("my-special-div");
    if (el.length) div = el[0];
    else div = 0;       

    if (!div) {
        // add div
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "my-special-div";
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("my-special-div")[0].remove();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

I guess the question can be posed more generally: how do I keep any state info about the things that are created in the content script that can also be accessed by the content script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code *checks* for a `class` but it *sets* the `id`.  [These are very different](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php) and if there might be more than one of these `div`s, then class is the correct property/attribute to use.

my-script.js should be like:

```
var div = 0;
self.port.on ("myaction", function (color) {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName ("my-special-div");
    if (el.length) div = el[0];
    else div = 0;       

    if (!div) {
        // add div
        div = document.createElement ("div");
        div.classList.add ("my-special-div")
        document.body.appendChild (div);
    }
    else {
        div.remove ();
    }
} );
```

Comment: duh, hate it when i overlook something simple.